Streaming a subtitle track with an RTSP stream using the live555 library
Is it possible to have a subtitle track that I can stream with my video and audio on my RTSP server using the live555 library? If so what format should I use for maximum compatibility? I've done some research and it seems that common subtitle formats like WebVTT and SubRip don't support live-streaming. I also know that the live555 library has a T140 RTPSink which I was able to get work but I can't get any subtitles displayed on the client-side using ffplay and/or vlc since T140 is a generic text transporter. Note that I am not interested in making a custom client-side rtsp receiver, and I am looking for maximum compatibility.

I haven't used Live555, but... CEA-708?
